# Windows cmd: escape commands to start cmd from batch file, executing commands that add to PATH

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, escape-characters

I would like to that a cmd command prompt, which maps a network directory to a local path, and then adds that local path to the (local) PATH variable.

I have prepared this kind of .bat script, which runs as expected:

```
pushd \\NetworkPath\Users\myname\Downloads
chdir
SET CurrentDir="%~dp0"
SET var=%cd% & SET CDIR=`chdir`
for /f "usebackq" %%x in (`chdir`) do set bvar=%%x
SET PATH=%PATH%;%bvar%
@echo IT IS: %CurrentDir%, %var%, %CDIR%, %bvar% ;;; %PATH% ---  %CD%
```

Essentially, this is the script I'd like to run upon the start of new `cmd.exe` when I run the `.bat` file. The problem is that when a network path is "mounted" (e.g. when `pushd` is invoked), it always gets a new and different local drive letter (X:, Y:, Z: ...), so I have to detect what this local drive path equivalent is (e.g. via `chdir`) before I can add it to PATH for that session; and also, I'm puzzled why `SET PATH=%PATH%;%bvar%` always doubles the semicolon `;` before the appended part, when the final concatenated `PATH` is `echo`ed.

I've learned that percent sign `%` is escaped by doubling it (`%%`); that ampersand `&` is the separator to concatenate multiple lines of code into a single line, which is escaped with caret `^`, but I'm still puzzled as double quotes `"` seem to end up verbatim in either variables via SET, or out of `echo`; also the `for` command always seems to execute (and I cannot escape it with caret) - even if it is a part of a SET variable statement.

So ultimately, I cannot get this script converted to a one-liner, so I can use it as an argument to `start.exe` as startup commands; note that I would not like to have two batch files, I'd like to have only one. I'd like to first store this script in a variable, so I can echo it for debugging - and this is how far I got:

```
SET TCMD="" pushd \\NetworkPath\Users\myname\Downloads ^& chdir ^& SET CurrentDir="%%~dp0" ^& SET var=^%%cd^%% ^& SET CDIR=^(`chdir`) ^& SET PATH=%%PATH%%;%%CD%% ^& echo %%CurrentDir%%, %%var%%, %%CDIR%%, %%bvar%% ;;; %%PATH%% ---  %%CD%% ""
echo %TCMD%
start cmd.exe /k "%TCMD%"
```

Problem - the new cmd.exe starts with:

```
'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then, `%CD%` refers to the *previous* directory (one the .bat script was started from), not to the new one.

None of these retrieve the new drive/path name when ran like this - except maybe `` for /f "usebackq" %%x in (`chdir`) ``, which I cannot really capture (I can see its output), and doesn't seem all that consistent either (sometimes it seems it reports empty).

How can I get my first script escaped, so it can serve as a one-liner in the `start` argument of my second script, so I can start `cmd.exe` terminal as intended?

References:

- http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows
- [Can you browse a UNC path using a command line environment without mapping it to a network drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/282963/can-you-browse-a-unc-path-using-a-command-line-environment-without-mapping-it-to)
- [Batch file that runs cmd.exe, a command, and then stays open at prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/106848/batch-file-that-runs-cmd-exe-a-command-and-then-stays-open-at-prompt)
- [Execute multiple commands with 1 line in Windows commandline?](https://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline)

Comment: What is the goal? You open a window to open a new one, this is your goal? If that's it, just create a batch opening another with the start command

Answer (score 2):

You are way over thinking this. You can't seem to see the forest for the trees ;-)

First off, `"%~dp0"` gives the location of your currently executing script, ***not*** the current directory.

Secondly, you are already using `%CD%` to print out the current directory at the end - why not use it when you extend your PATH !?

```
@echo off
pushd "\\NetworkPath\Users\myname\Downloads"
path %path%;"%cd%"
```