# How to run multiple commands one after another in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How to run Windows OS cmd.exe multiple commands one after another, 
I use `ncrack`, commands

I manually open cmd.exe and I paste this code:

```
ncrack --user Admin -P pass1.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f
```

When pass1.txt is finished I paste manually to cmd.exe the second command,
which contains the Pass2.txt etc...:

```
ncrack --user Admin -P pass2.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f
```

then I paste manually to cmd, Pass.3txt

```
ncrack --user Admin -P pass3.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f
```

How can I run all  commands automatically in a batch file, one after
 another and not all at the same time?

Comment: This question is upvoted and has upvoted answers, few people found it helpful. Please don't spoil it.

Comment: Why are you trying to delete this question and answers? Is it because it uses `ncrack` as example? Because `ncrack` targets particular IP? If so, the right thing to do is to change the example command, not to nuke the entire question. If you tell us your reasons we may work something out.

Comment: I replaced the actual IP address with `<IPAddress>` in case that is your concern as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute multiple commands with 1 line in Windows commandline?](https://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run multiple commands one after another in cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/1079403/how-to-run-multiple-commands-one-after-another-in-cmd/1079420#1079420) o{[]|||||||}::;;::;;::;;::;;::;;::;;::> ♦♦♦

Answer (score 97):

## **Run multiple commands one after another in cmd**

Try using the conditional execution `&` or the `&&` between each command either with a copy and paste into the cmd.exe window or in a batch file.

Additionally, you can use the double pipe `||` symbols instead to only run the next command if the previous command failed.

**Execute command2 after execution of command1 has finished**

```
ncrack --user Admin -P pass1.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f & ncrack --user Admin -P pass2.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f & ncrack --user Admin -P pass3.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f
```

**Execute command2 only if execution of command1 has finished successfully**

```
ncrack --user Admin -P pass1.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f && ncrack --user Admin -P pass2.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f && ncrack --user Admin -P pass3.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f
```

**Execute command2 only if execution of command1 has finished unsuccessfully**

```
ncrack --user Admin -P pass1.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f || ncrack --user Admin -P pass2.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f || ncrack --user Admin -P pass3.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Conditional Execution <sup>`[1]`</sup>](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)
- [Conditional Execution <sup>`[2]`</sup>](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

Answer (score 34):

Use below syntax in your cmd file.

```
call command1    
call command2
.    
.    
call commandx
```

Example:

```
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=spring.jar -DgroupId=com.td.tdi.creditProtection.webservice -DartifactId=spring -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar -DgroupId=com.td.tdi.creditProtection.webservice -DartifactId=com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar 
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar -DgroupId=com.td.tdi.creditProtection.webservice -DartifactId=com.ibm.ws.runtime -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=IMSConnection_Utilities.jar -DgroupId=com.td.tdi.creditProtection.webservice -DartifactId=IMSConnection_Utilities -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: I mean ... that's exactly is the command I am trying to run multiple times

Comment: Clean. The *call* does not care if a command fails, it just runs the next call, precisely what I wanted.

Answer (score 7):

You can enter both commands on the same line and separate them with either a single ampersand (which causes them to be run in sequence) or two ampersands (which introduces simple error checking: the second command only runs if the first one was successful)

e.g.:

```
ncrack --user Admin -P pass1.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f && ncrack --user Admin -P pass2.txt <IPAddress>:3389 -oN good.txt -f
```

[Source](https://htipe.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/multiple-commands-on-a-single-windows-command-line/)

Comment: I see JUICED_IT beat me to posting this solution :)

Comment: @MunteanCosminManim Changing your requirements after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've already received.

Comment: is not legal i ask to delete it plz

Answer (score 6):

Just add all the commands line by line in a batch file, and save the file as somename.bat.

Execute that batch file; all the commands would run sequentially in the order of their presence in the file.

How to execute the batch file through cmd:

```
path/to/the/directory/of/your/batchfile/somename.bat
```

Comment: @MunteanCosminManim - They would be running one after another, not at the same time. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: @MunteanCosminManim Yes, this is how a batch file works. It executes a command and waits until the command is finished, then runs the next command. In order to execute a command and immediately continue to the next, you'll have to use the command `call` or  `start` too.

Comment: No, "all the commands would run sequentially" is wrong. Try del and ren on like 50 files, the ren will throw error of duplicate names.

Answer (score 1):

All I did was paste the commands. 
For instance, to better my Internet connection I pasted:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh int ip reset 
netsh winsock reset
```

Press the right click on your mouse, and whether on cmd or powershell it automatically executes all of them in sequence. 
You don't even have to press 'enter'. Simple! (the last one i.e 'netsh winsock reset'was the only one I had to press enter for as it did not run automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Use ^& instead of & to escape the special meaning of & in Windows batch scripts. This allows the & operator to be correctly interpreted as part of the command.

```
start cmd /k cd /D "Client_Server_Parallel" ^& make -f "%MAKEFILE%" run_server
```